# Unable to get form to submit and post user data to mydatabase

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I keep getting a white label error and it just says

> Request method 'POST' not supported

This is the Controller.

```
@GetMapping(value="/get")
  public List<Contacts> getAll() {
  return contactsRepo.findAll();
}    

 @PostMapping(value = "/contactMe.html")
   public List<Contacts> persist(@RequestBody final Contacts contacts{ 
       contactsRepo.save(contacts);
   return contactsRepo.findAll();
 }

 /**
 @PutMapping(value = "/put")
   public List<Contacts> contactSubmit(@ModelAttribute Contacts 
       contacts) { 
     contactsRepo.save(contacts);
     return contactsRepo.findAll();
 }
 **/
```

This is the HTML form.

```
   <form th:action="@{contactMe}" method="POST" 
    th:modelAttribute="contacts">

    <div class="form-main">
    <div class="form-content">
    <h1>First Name:</h1> <input type="text" th:field="*{first_name}">

<h1>Last Name:</h1> <input type="text" name="lastName"th:field="* 
 {last_name}">

<h1>Email:</h1><br> <input type="text" name="email"th:field="{email}">

<h1>Phone Number:</h1><br> <input type="text" name="telephone"th:field="* 
  {phone_number}">

    <input type="submit" name="Submit">
    </div>
    </div>

   </form>
```

I am able to post data using postman via application/json in postmapping. I want to be able to submit user input to post to db.

Comment: try this <form th:method="POST"  th:action="@{/contactMe}" AND USE  @PostMapping(value = "/contactMe", produces="text/html")

Answer (score 1):

```
@PostMapping(value = "/contactMe",produces="text/html")
 @ResponseBody
   public List<Contacts> persist(@ModelAttribute final Contacts contacts{ 
       contactsRepo.save(contacts);
   return contactsRepo.findAll();
 }
```

And HTML form use

```
<form th:action="@{contactMe}" method="POST" th:modelAttribute="contacts">
```

Comment: can you try with  @RequestMapping(value = "/contactMe", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = "text/html")

Answer (score 0):

your form should have a attribute called th:action="/contactMe.html" , currently that's the only path available by post that u created in your controller, your th:object is what u send to the controller. I dont think that code compile because is missing a ")" after contacts parameter. here you  have a basic example https://spring.io/guides/gs/handling-form-submission/

Answer (score 0):

**Check if you are returning a @ResponseBody or a @ResponseStatus**

When calling with a POST request I always got the following error:

**HTTP Status 405 - Request method 'POST' not supported**

After a while, I figured out that the method was actually called, but because there is no @ResponseBody and no @ResponseStatus Spring MVC raises the error.

To fix this simply add a `@ResponseBody`

```
@RequestMapping(value="/user", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody List<Contacts> persist(@RequestBody final Contacts contacts{ 
   contactsRepo.save(contacts);
   return contactsRepo.findAll();
}
```

or a `@ResponseStatus` to your method.

```
 @RequestMapping(value="/contactMe", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    @ResponseStatus(value=HttpStatus.OK)
    public List<Contacts> persist(@RequestBody final Contacts contacts{ 
       contactsRepo.save(contacts);
   return contactsRepo.findAll();
}
```

Comment: @GetMapping("/contactMe")
 public String hasContactedMe(Model model) {
  model.addAttribute("contactMeForm", new Contacts());
  return "contactMe";
 }
 
 @PostMapping(value="/contactMe")
    @ResponseStatus(value=HttpStatus.OK)
    public List<Contacts> persist(@RequestBody final Contacts contacts){ 
       contactsRepo.save(contacts);
   return contactsRepo.findAll();
 }                                                                                                                                                          This is my controller, to post in /contactMe

Comment: I want the "/contactMe" page to take input and that input goes to my db and page goes to a another page saying thank you.